# Request for clarification on section 107.1b of the Comprehensive rules (Numbers and Symbols)

Tags: magic-the-gathering

In section 107.1b of the Comprehensive rules there is an example where power and toughness of a creature change in a way that I find confusing.

Example: [Chameleon Colossus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Chameleon%20Colossus) is a 4/4 creature with the ability “{2}{G}{G}: Chameleon Colossus gets +X/+X until end of turn, where X is its power.” An effect gives it -6/-0, then its ability is activated. It remains a -2/4 creature. It doesn’t become -4/2.

I don't understand why the creature doesn't become a -4/2 creature. In my mind the creature has a base power and toughness of 4/4 which is first modified to -2/4 and subsequently to -4/2 (for a duration). It would seem to me that the only way for the power and toughness values to not change is if X is zero or the effect from the ability is ignored for some reason. But X is not zero since the base power has changed from 4 to -2. Neither is there a reason to ignore the effect from the ability.

Is the meaning of the text that a creature can "become" something else if it undergoes a change in characteristics which is separate from the creature being subject to modifier values that cause a temporary change in the interpretation of it's characteristics? In the example the base power and toughness of the creature is 4/4, which are modified by the first effect to -2/4, changing the characteristics of the creature? The Colossus thus "becomes a -2/4 creature". There is then the effect from the activation of the creature's ability which causes a temporary interpretation of the characteristics to -4/2 until end of turn. In this sense the creature "doesn't become -4/2" since the characteristics do not change from -2/4 but are merely subject to a temporary modifier value.

I'm a new player (haven't even played a game yet) trying to get an overview of the rules, so I might not be using the correct terms ("effects", "characteristics", "objects").

Answer (score 8):

The reason is rule 107.1b itself:

> Most of the time, the Magic game uses only positive numbers and zero. You can’t choose a negative number, deal negative damage, gain negative life, and so on. However, it’s possible for a game value, such as a creature’s power, to be less than zero. If a calculation or comparison needs to use a negative value, it does so. **If a calculation that would determine the result of an effect yields a negative number, zero is used instead, unless that effect doubles or sets to a specific value a player’s life total or the power and/or toughness of a creature or creature card.**

*Adding* to power and toughness does not fall under any of the exceptions, thus 0 is used instead of −2.

(Under some earlier versions of the rules, the exceptions were different and did include this case of adding to power and/or toughness; it would have become −4/2 under those versions of the rules.)

Comment: I still don't follow. Take the calculation to determine the new power. This calculation adds -2 to -2, yielding the answer -4.  Following the logic of the paragraph quoted:  whenever the calculation needs to *use* a negative number (-2), it uses it. ("If the calculation needs to use a negative value, it does so"). But this *yields* a negative number, -4. Then the rule tells us: "zero is used instead". I am not clear what this means: 0 is used instead of the *answer*, or 0 is used instead of one/both of the negative *inputs*. (cont...)

Comment: (...cont) It seems there are 3 options. (a) 0 is used instead of the answer. We end up with 0 power. (b) 0 is used instead of both the -2s in the calculation. We still end up with 0 power. (c) 0 is used instead of just one of the -2s in the calculation. We would end up with -2 power. But this again "yields a negative number", so we should replace the other -2 by 0 also, and we're back in case (b). Whichever way I try to construe this, I seem to end up with 0 as a result.

Comment: OK, I think I see what is happening. "Calculation that would determine the result of an effect" here means "calculation of the amount by which the power will change", not "calculation of the eventual power". That's quite a confusing use of English - "result" of something normally refers to the situation *after* that thing has been applied.

Comment: @James The calculation is "add -2 to the creature's power". You can't add a negative number to power, so you add zero. The same way, you can't gain negative life, or draw negative cards.

Comment: @doppelgreener Where does the rule say you can't add a negative number to power? It explicitly says you *can* use a negative number in a calculation: "If a calculation needs to use a negative number, it does so".

Comment: It's the next sentence: that you'd add -2 power is the calculation. I don't know what else to tell you.

Comment: @doppelgreener Your comments don't seem to agree with each other. According to your second comment, the relevant calculation (which we don't accept a negative answer to) is "determine what number to add to the creature's power", not "add -2 to the creature's power". Is that right?

Comment: @JamesMartin Buddy I have not figured out the best way to explain the rule but I'm doing my best here. I think you're overthinking it. If something tries to add some amount of power but the amount we add is going to be negative, we add zero. That's all.

Comment: @doppelgreener I very much appreciate the help! Definitely didn't mean to suggest otherwise. Clearly you are right about what the outcome is. The question is: why does rule 101.7b have that outcome? Probably I'm hung up on something here, but the sticking point does seem to be what the meaning is of "calculation that would determine the result of an effect". I'm sure someone will come along and clear everything up in due course :)

Comment: The text of Chameleon Colossus's ability is "Chameleon Colossus gets +X/+X until end of turn, where X is its power." The calculation that would determine the result of the effect is calculating the value of X. If that calculation results in a negative number, 0 is used instead.

Comment: Also, for context, they changed this rule a few years ago to prevent Death's Shadow from getting buffed beyond 13/13 when its controller has negative life. Death's Shadow has the ability "Death's Shadow gets -X/-X, where X is your life total." And again, the relevant calculation is the calculation of the value of X.

Comment: OK I see, interesting! Thanks @murgatroid99 and all.

Comment: @m90 But in the example given with the rule the text says "An effect gives it -6/-0". In my understanding this would translate to "4 + (-6) = -2", which would be a calculation determining the result of an effect yielding a negative number.

Comment: @ doppelgreener You said that "You can't add a negative number to power, so you add zero". But that's what the text from the example seems to do as I showed above. Also, as m90 said, under some earlier versions of the rules the creature would have become -4/2. That is, the calculation would have been "-2 + (-2) = -4".

Comment: I'm also inclined to agree with James Martin that interpreting the phrase "Calculation that would determine the result of an effect" to mean "Calculation of the amount by which the power will change" seems confusing. Does the substitution of the variable for its value determine the result of the larger expression more than the larger expression itself? One variable is just one term of an expression after all.

Comment: Also it seems to me that the effect does in fact double the power of the creature. The card text says "Chameleon Colossus gets +X/+X until end of turn, where X is its power”. Increasing something by the value it has just means doubling of the value.